# uitableview cell still doesn't delete properly the first time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, grand-central-dispatch

So my goal is to be able to delete tableview cells with one go and not have to worry about trying to delete twice. I have a method for deleting cells out of the tableview which in addition also deletes a record out of an Algolia index and a document out of a Firestore collection.

Here is that method:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (deleted, view, completion) in
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Event", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this event?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let deleteEvent = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (deletion) in
            guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
            let documentid = self.documentsID[indexPath.row].docID
            let algoliaID = self.algoliaObjectID[indexPath.row].algoliaObjectID
            let deleteIndex = client.index(withName: IndexName(rawValue: user.uid))
            
            self.getTheSchoolsID { (id) in
                guard let id = id else { return }
                self.db.collection("student_users").whereField("school_id", isEqualTo: id).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("Couldn't fetch the student users.")
                        return
                    }
                    let group = DispatchGroup()
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        group.enter()
                        let userUUID = document.documentID
                        self.db.collection("student_users/\(userUUID)/events_bought").whereField("eventID", isEqualTo: documentid).getDocuments { (querySnapshotTwo, error) in
                            guard error == nil else {
                                print("Couldn't fetch if student users are purchasing this event")
                                return
                            }
                            guard querySnapshotTwo?.isEmpty == true else {
                                self.showAlert(title: "Students Have Purchased This Event", message: "This event cannot be deleted until all students who have purchased this event have completely refunded their purchase of this event. Please be sure to make an announcement that this event will be deleted.")
                                return
                            }
                            group.leave()
                    }
                        
                    }
                    
                    group.notify(queue: .main) {
                        
                        deleteIndex.deleteObject(withID: ObjectID(rawValue: algoliaID)) { (result) in
                            if case .success(let response) = result {
                                print("Algolia document successfully deleted: \(response.wrapped)")
                            }
                        }


                        self.db.document("school_users/\(user.uid)/events/\(documentid)").delete { (error) in
                            guard error == nil else {
                                print("There was an error deleting the document.")
                                return
                            }
                            print("Deleted")
                        }
                        self.eventName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                        tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        alert.addAction(deleteEvent)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed

    
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
    
}
```

Pretty straightforward, I recently added the `DispatchGroup` blocks to fix some UI issues as well as the Firestore query but other than that it was just what was in the `group.notify()` before that.

Now for some reason when I try to delete the cells, it will delete and show the print messages as if it deleted successfully, but when I search in the searchbar that I've placed in the view controller, I can still see the cell in the search results. This basically means that not only was the record not deleted from Algolia but the document from Firestore was not deleted either.
Yes the cell was removed from the tableview after the deletion, but as soon as I search for it and tap on it, it instantiates the view controller and displays all the fields from the Firestore document. As soon as I tap out of that view controller, the cell then appears back in the tableview and requires me to delete it again for it to actually work.

So the question is, with the function I've provided, how can I make sure cell is deleted properly the first time?

Comment: `deleteIndex.deleteObject` and `document(...).delete` are both asynchronous, right? But, you're reloading the table view before either of those functions are completed.

Comment: So take the `tableview.reloadData()` out of the `group.notify()`? @jnpdx

Comment: Honestly, I never use dispatch groups, as I prefer either Combine or callback handlers, but I can tell that you need to be waiting for the deletes to finish before you reload, which you aren't doing.

Comment: It was what I was told to use [in this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996582/firestore-document-deletes-and-crashes-with-an-error-in-logic-but-deletes-fine-w). For some reason when I tested it out, yesterday, it deleted perfectly fine every time like 15 times in a row, so I don't know if it was maybe a one time glitch. I have no experience with Combine and I could use a callback handler but this seems to work fine for now. @jnpdx

Comment: It seems like a loose interpretation of what that answer says. It *is* where that answer says to do the deleting, but it doesn't say what to do about side effects from those deletes, which again, I'm *positive* are asynchronous functions themselves.

Comment: Keen on taking the bool callback handler function route, but I need the `let documentid = self.documentsID[indexPath.row].docID` in order for the query to work, and I can only access that in the tableview method.  If I was to somehow pull this off, I can then be able to order the async tasks using dispatchSemaphore and fix the deletion issue permanently. Any workaround suggestions? @jnpdx

Comment: I don't understand why you would need callbacks and semaphores. If it were me, I'd write it with callback functions and pass the necessary information through the functions.

Comment: I said I needed the specific line of code `let documentid = self.documentsID[indexPath.row].docID`, but yes I would need those as well. I completely understand why you'd do what you said and I would do the same but I don't have access to the `indexPath.row` parameter like I do in the tableview method. I need the semaphores because the tasks go in random order every time I try to delete a cell and I need it to be in a specific order every time so the user doesn't have to worry about trying to delete a cell twice. @jnpdx

Comment: I don't understand why you only have access to the docID there and can't pass it from function to function. Semaphores wouldn't be needed if you use callbacks and only call the next function once the previous one had completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @dante comment, the method in the description works for now, however:

- Currently, the code above reloads the table view before either of those functions are completed.
- As @jnpdx mentioned, the right approach would be to wait for the deletion to end before reloading the table view because `deleteIndex.deleteObject` and `document(...).delete` are both asynchronous functions.